# Avoiding create databasechangelog table in Liquibase

Tags: sql, liquibase, ddl

I want to generate a SQL file to update my database's databasechangelog table with `changeLogSyncSQL` via command-line. When I generate the SQL file there is a `CREATE TABLE [DATABASECHANGELOG]` in it, which is alright when I use the SQL file for the first time on a database but what can I do to generate a SQL file without this `CREATE TABLE [DATABASECHANGELOG]` statement since then there will already be a databasechangelog table in the database. It is no option to run it directly against a database.

My properties file:

```
driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
classpath: sqljdbc42.jar
url: offline:mssql?outputLiquibaseSql=true
changeLogFile: cl.xml
outputFile: output.sql
```

I am using liquibase 3.5.5.

Comment: Why is it a problem that the table is create if you are planning to use Liquibase for that database anyway?

Comment: Because there are cases where in the database will already be a databasechangelog table

Comment: That doesn't matter. If the table is already there, Liquibase will not fail

Comment: Yeah that's right, thank you!